# Spring boot parameter update model Database don't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

i set the value to update value so that a table will be created in the database automatically corresponding to defined data model.
But it does not work, what it wrong with my properties ?
Database: Mysql

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=2MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=2MB


server.port=8081
server.servlet.session.timeout=1200
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false&zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.storage.storage_engine=innodb

spring.security.user.name="root"
spring.security.user.password="123"
spring.resources.add-mappings=true
```

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test.files' doesn't exist
```

What genereted conflict with "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the database connection string is valid.
Try changing `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false&zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC`

The name of your database is "test" but is it really?

Comment: Yes it's that , created with xampp.

Comment: Inconsistent capitalized naming convention of the database tables may also be a problem that leads to this issue

Comment: Spring have a cache, because I put all in lowercase and created a new (empty) database "testdb" , but I still have access to the old one